# Do people seek God?

Tags: romans, isaiah, deuteronomy

Romans 3:11
New International Version

> there is no one who understands; there is **no one** who seeks God.

Deuteronomy 4:29

> But if from there you will seek the LORD your God, you will find Him **if you seek Him** with all your heart and with all your soul.

Isaiah 55:6

> Seek the LORD while he may be found; call on him while he is near.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoa - not so fast!  In Rom 3:10-18, Paul is clearly describing unregenerate, unconverted people.  In this natural human condition:

- No one is righteous (v10)
- No one who understands (v11)
- No one who seeks God (v11)
- All have turned away [From God] (v12)
- All are worthless (v12)
- No one who does good (v12)
- Throats are open graves and tongues practice deceit, venom on their lips (v13)
- Mouths full of cursing and bitterness (v14)
- Their feet are swift to shed blood (v15)
- ruin and misery lie in their wake (v16)
- and the way of peace they have not known (v17)
- no fear of God before their eyes (v18)

It is precisely this wicked state of the human condition from which Jesus came to save us.  David summed this up when he said (Ps 51:5):

> Surely I was brought forth in iniquity; I was sinful when my mother
> conceived me.

In 1 Cor 6:9-11 Paul makes a similar point that applies to all of us:

> Do you not know that the wicked will not inherit the kingdom of God?
> Do not be deceived: Neither the sexually immoral, nor idolaters, nor
> adulterers, nor men who submit to or perform homosexual acts, nor
> thieves, nor the greedy, nor drunkards, nor verbal abusers, nor
> swindlers, will inherit the kingdom of God. And that is what some of
> you were. **But you were washed, you were sanctified, you were
> justified, in the name of the Lord Jesus Christ and by the Spirit of
> our God.**

Thus, while we come to God as we are, we do not stay as we are but by the miracle of the Holy Spirit which lives in the Christian, we are changed and the process of restoring image of God in us begins:

- Christians have “the mind of Christ”, 1 Cor 2:16
- Converted Christian are to be transformed by the renewing of the mind, Rom 12:2
- Christians are to be like God and “follow God’s example”, Eph 5:1
- By beholding the Messiah, Jesus Christ, 2 Cor 3:18. We are “transformed into His image”
- Jesus’ final instruction to the disciples was to go and make more disciples, Matt 28:19
- Followers of Jesus are called, “Christians”, = “like Christ”, Acts 11:26
- When Jesus returns, we will “be like Him”, 1 John 3:2
- The highest attainment of a follower of Christ is to “know the Lord”, Heb 8:11

**CONCLUSION**

Rom 3:10-18 is describing unregenerate, pre-conversion people who are opposed to God and everything about God.  God calls us to a holy life and for those who respond and do not reject God's call to holiness, are converted to service and Christ-likeness as described in places like Deut 4:29, Isa 55:6.  In the latter case, the following verse (Isa 55:7) makes this clear:

> Let the wicked man forsake his own way and the unrighteous man his own
> thoughts; let him return to the LORD, that He may have compassion, and
> to our God, for He will freely pardon.